# Is it possible to use multiple service keys in the same command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We wanted to copy a file from one project's storage to another.

I have credentials for project A and project B in separate service accounts.

The only way we knew how to copy files was to add service key credential permissions to the bucket's access control list.

Is there some other way to run commands across accounts using multiple service keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview) to accomplish this.

The docs should guide you to [setup the permissions for buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/configure-access) in both projects and do the transfers [programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program) or on [the console](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console).

You need to get the service account email associated to the Storage Transfer Service by entering your project ID in the [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/get) page. You then need to give this service account email the required roles to access the data from the source. [Storage Object Viewer should be enough permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/iam-transfer#source-permissions).

At the data destination, you need get the service account email for the second project ID, then give it the Storage Legacy Bucket Writer role.

You can then do the transfer using the snippets in the docs.